# Нужна ли запятая после "в случае"?

Tags: пунктуация, спп, союзы

В случае если ОТЕЛЬ будет вынужден переселить клиента ДИСТРИБЬЮТОРА в другой номер, ОТЕЛЬ обязуется за свой счет выполнить следующее...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Нужна ли запятая?

Не нужна.

***В случае если*** — союз, присоединяющий придаточную часть сложноподчиненного предложения со значением реального условия.

См. [**"Справочник по пунктуации"**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_122) на Грамоте.ру:

> **В СЛУЧАЕ(,) ЕСЛИ**, союз
>
> Придаточные предложения, присоединяемые союзом «в случае(,) если»,
>   выделяются (или отделяются) запятыми. При этом союз может целиком
>   входить в придаточную часть (и не разделяться запятой), но может и
>   расчленяться (в этом случае запятая ставится между частями союза,
>   перед словом «если»). О факторах, влияющих на расстановку знаков
>   препинания, см. в **Прил. 3**.

[**Приложение 3:**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum/punctum-attach3)

> Придаточная часть в сложноподчиненном предложении может присоединяться
>   к главной с помощью составных подчинительных союзов, например: *ввиду
>   того что, вместо того чтобы, **в случае если**, несмотря на то что, перед
>   тем как, потому что, прежде чем* и др.
>
> <...>
>
> **Если придаточная часть предшествует главной** – запятая ставится только после всего придаточного предложения.
>
> <...>
>
> ***В случае если*** Исполнитель не выполнил своих обязательств в сроки, указанные в настоящем Договоре, Заказчик вправе расторгнуть Договор.